# EtherCard library initialization not working with 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

So I spent a good amount of time trying to understand why a certain code won't work and another would, and I am pretty confident that I found why, but don't know how to fix it.

I am trying to better my skills by understanding why the following code wasn't initializing.

So here we go.

For sake of simplicity within my code I wanted to select the Mac address and IP I was going to use through a 2D array:

```cpp
static byte MacRanger[4][6] = {
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA1},
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA2},
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA3}
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA4},
};

static byte IPRanger[4][4] = {
  {192,168,253,1},
  {192,168,253,2},
  {192,168,253,3},
  {192,168,253,4},
};
```

I really liked this idea because it allowed me to have a single initialization code with the help of `getChannel()` that returns me the index at which to get the Mac & IP.
--Edited--
I did ensure that getChannel was giving me the proper output & and tried hardcoded `MacRanger[0]` & `IPRanger[0]` for diagnostics purpurses

```cpp
static byte IPGateway[] = {192,168,253,254};
static byte IPDns[] = {8,8,8,8};
static byte IPMask[] = {255,255,255,0};
ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, MacRanger[getChannel() - 1], SS)
ether.staticSetup(IPRanger[getChannel() - 1], IPGateway,IPDns,IPMask);
```

This compiles but doesn't work, with no error.

On the other hand, if I do the following, it does work:

```cpp
static byte MacRanger1[] = {0x70,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0xA1};
static byte MacRanger2[] = {0x70,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0xA2};
static byte MacRanger3[] = {0x70,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0xA3};
static byte MacRanger4[] = {0x70,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0xA4};

static byte IPRanger1[] = {192,168,253,1};
static byte IPRanger2[] = {192,168,253,2};
static byte IPRanger3[] = {192,168,253,3};
static byte IPRanger4[] = {192,168,253,4};
    
ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, MacRanger1, SS)
ether.staticSetup(IPRanger1, IPGateway,IPDns,IPMask);
```

My assumption are that it's because there is a null char that is needed.

So I decided to add '\0' to all my MAC and IP 2D array and shifting the size by one more. Like the following

```cpp
static byte MacRanger[4][7] = {
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA1,'\0'},
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA2,'\0'},
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA3,'\0'},
  {0xED,0xA7,0xA0,0x9C,0xEE,0xA4,'\0'},
};

static byte IPRanger[4][5] = {
  {192,168,253,1,'\0'},
  {192,168,253,2,'\0'},
  {192,168,253,3,'\0'},
  {192,168,253,4,'\0'},
};
```

That still didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: check that `getChannel()` is actually returning the value you expect?

Comment: I should have mentionned this in post.
I did hardcode a int =1 as return and also straight up omit the `getChannel()` function and select the 0,1,2 and 3 index compiled and test all combination.

its like I said, I don't know how both of those solution differ, yet it does not work.
Like explain in OP Im thinking this has to do with the termination byte of the array

Comment: according to the documentation the inputs are fixed size, so termination makes no difference (as is born out by your last attempt)

Comment: The MAC addresses in your "not working" snippets are different to the addresses in the "working", perhaps that is the issue

Comment: @M.M interesting point...
I can't remember at what point I changed the mac addresses through-out this trial and error process.
I will check this tomorrow

If I may ask you as I see you have some experience under your belt.
From a technical stand point, Am I correct to believe both of the solution passing the byte array to the method are exactly the same apart from the Mac addresses being different ?

Comment: Yes they are the same apart from thea ddresses differing